# Why doesn this MatLab Gauss-Seidel Iterative solver get stuck in a loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration, linear-algebra, gaussian

I have spent the last five hours trying to understand why this code gets stuck in an infinite loop. I swear I'm following the instructions I find online and elsewhere exactly. It feels like everything I'm trying doesn't work and I have no clue why.

```
function [ K ] = linearSolve( a, b )
%Solves a system of equations. a = matrix of equations ; b = matrix
%of solutions

clear all
clc


%Example Matrices

a = [2,1,3;-2,-3,1;-3,4,-1];
b = [1,0,3];


%Defining initial & user values...

allowedError = input('Enter your max allowed error before stopping, in %: ');
X = input('Enter your inital guess matrix X: ');
dims = size(a);
iterations = 1;
maxiter = input('Maximum iterations: ');
error = allowedError + 100;


%Setting up K[i,j] matrix:

for r = 1:dims(1)

    for c = 1:dims(2)
        K(r,c) = -1*a(r,c)/a(r,r);

        if r == c
            K(r,c) = 0;
        end
    end

    d(r) = b(r) / a(r,r);
end


%Performing Iteration...

while error > allowedError

    iterations = iterations + 1;

    prevGuess = X;
    for j = 1:dims(1)

        X(j) = K(j,:)*X(:) + d(j);
        error(j) = abs(((X(j) - prevGuess(j))/X(j))*100);
    end

    if (allowedError >= error) | (iterations >= maxiter)
        break
    end
end


%Display Results
disp('The values of X are: ');
disp(X);
disp('------------------------------------');
disp('The error is: ');
disp(error);

end
```

Comment: What is your `K[i,j]` matrix and why don't you use matrix notation?

Comment: This code does not get stuck in an infinite loop. Show us what inputs you give.

Comment: The inputs I give are listed in the function (At the top) I typically use a guess of [0,0,0],[1,2,3] etc... for X allowedError is typically 0.001 (Expressed in percent) The K[i,j] matrix is a square matriz wth zeros along the diagonal.